ORA-00937 when reading a group by subquery
I am relatively new to Oracle Db, and this might be something stupid, but I cannot find what is the problem with this query. I get ORA-00937: not a single-group group function when I run it.
select a.col_a, a.col_b, a.amt
from (
    select col_a, col_b, sum(col_c) as amt
    from table_a
    group by col_a, col_b
) a
where a.amt <> 0;

The subquery, by itself, works. To make matters worse, this also works:
select *
from (
    select col_a, col_b, sum(col_c) as amt
    from table_a
    group by col_a, col_b
) a;

This is obviously an illustration, I cannot post the actual code, but please trust me that there are valid reasons to organize the code in this manner.
I have also tried using CTE for the subquery, but nothing changed. Wrapping select * as another subquery also didn't help.
The weird thing is that the error suggests that I am using an aggregate function without a correct group by clause, but the subquery that does aggregation works.
I could work around this using a temp table, but it seems wasteful.

There is nothing wrong with code, as @tim-biegeleisen notes.
After thinking myself crazy, I tried to execute it from SQL Developer instead of TOAD, and it works just fine.
The "problem" appears to stem from the fact that the code is in a .pkb file.

If I try to run just this statement using "Execute/compile statement" from TOAD, it returns the error.
If I run it using "Execute as script" it works; the package also compiles.
If I run it in a separate sql tab, also works.

I will leave this here, in hopes it will appear in someone's google search and save them a ton of time.

The first query you posted should not be throwing any error on Oracle.  That being said, you don't need, and arguably should not even be using, a subquery here.  Just make a single pass aggregation and then assert a positive sum using a HAVING clause:
SELECT col_a, col_b, SUM(col_c) as amt
FROM table_a
GROUP BY col_a, col_b
HAVING SUM(col_c) > 0;


Thanks. I've solved the issue. Posted code is just an illustration - I do more in the actual query, but that was not relevant, because the basic select fails, as described.
